# How is Java parameter reference and original reference (not object) the same?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So we know that `Java` uses pass by value, i.e. it passes a copy of the reference to the methods. 
I am wondering why is it then, that when I test the parameter reference (`param` in my example) with the original reference (`string` in my example) is says they are the same?

Shouldn't the following code return `false`, i.e. the references are not the same, because a copy reference (i.e. a new reference) is passed by value?

```
public class Interesting {

  private String string;

  public Interesting(final String interestig) {
    super();
    string = interestig; // original reference is tested against copy reference and it says they are the same
  }

  public boolean isItTheSame(final String param) {
    return param == string;
  }

  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    Interesting obj = new Interesting("String");
    System.out.println(obj.isItTheSame(obj.string)); //copy of reference is created here
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any part that creates a copy? Which part do you think creates a copy?

Comment: The OCA guide does: "The called method then gets its own copy of
the reference variable to do with it what it likes." Chapter Passing Variables into Methods - OCA Objective 6.8

Comment: @AndrewLi You are wrong. Atti quotes it correctly. The reference is copied. You think that is says that the object is copied, but this is not what this quote says. It's like copying a primitive value.

Comment: I wonder if "[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40480)" is still a suitable dupe, because it covers variables and references and their behaviour pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference is a value of its own.  The string `"String"` lives at a specific memory location, say 0x01ab64e.  Therefore, the value of any reference referring to that string is 0x01ab64e.  There can be no reference to that string with a different value,  because then it will not be referring to that string, it will be referring to a different string.

"Pass by value" refers to passing the reference by value, not passing the actual referenced object (the string) by value.  So, the exact same reference is passed.  That's why it is the same.

To verify that the reference is passed by value, (and that the value is a copy,) try this:

```
String s = null;
foo( s );
assert s == null;

void foo( String s )
{
    s = "not null";
}
```

The assertion does not fail, which means that the reference `s` held by the caller was not altered.  Which means that the reference `s` was passed by value, (which is always a copy,) so `foo()` only changed the value of its own copy of the reference, leaving the copy of the caller unaffected.

Comment: but is the parameter `s` (in the `foo` method) not a different reference then the `String s` in your first line?

Comment: @Atti You should really start to differ __variables__ and __references__. Two different variables (like `s` from the first line and `s` from the method parameter) still can have the same reference to the same String object in heap. They will then differ when you do `s = "not null"` in `foo`.

Comment: @Mike: I got it. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

A reference variable is a reference. It contains a specific bit pattern​ that identifies the location of an object. This is known in computer science as a *pointer*. [Per the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1), "reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to these objects". Pointer values, like primitives, are passed to methods just by their bit pattern. That same pattern means they point to the same object. That's what `==` checks, whether two pointers point to the same object. That's why you get that result.

Answer (score 1):

No, because == compares the *value* of the reference as well; it yields true if both references refer to the same object.

Comment: But they are not the same reference ... if we reassign the parameter reference the original object will not be affected.

Comment: @Atti This is correct, but you don't reassign anything here.

Comment: @Michael: but I thought that if we have two different references and == tests the references it would be false ... what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: @Atti: Two different references to the same object contain the same value, just like two different int variables can contain the same value, and in both cases the values are considered equal. And what would even be the point of comparing references for identity rather than equality? What would you need it for? That two references refer to the same object is a useful information in many circumstances.